# outlook mailitem reply with sent date time in c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have created Outlook add ins which create reply on incoming email based on some rule specified by user.

but i am getting one problem which describe as, when i create reply with outlook mailitem it dosent include from,sent,to,subject in body from incoming email like when we click reply button in outlook as shown in image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JEyi.png)

Here is my code which is creating reply for incoming email.

```
void mailreply(Outlook.MailItem Email)
{
   Outlook.MailItem replyMail = null;
   replyMail = IncomingEmail.Reply(); 
   replyMail.subject = "Abcd"
   replyMail.body = "XYZ";

    --------- rest of code -------
   replyMail.send();
 }
```

please help me to solve this problem, how can i add Incoming email datetime and from,sent etc to reply body.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, i am posting here if any one have same issue then they can refer this post

```
void mailreply(Outlook.MailItem Email)
{
   Outlook.MailItem replyMail = null;
   replyMail = IncomingEmail.Reply(); 
   replyMail.subject = "Abcd"
   replyMail.body = "XYZ";

  //Answer bellow
   replyMail.To = Email.FromAddress;
   replyMail.ReceveDateTime = Email.SentDateTime; 
    --------- rest of code -------
   replyMail.send();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should expand your code to place these lines in replyMail.body